# Multiple invisible recaptchas always send empty g-recaptcha-response

Tags: invisible-recaptcha

I'm using the new invisible recaptcha on my website, and in the homepage I have two forms with recaptcha validation.
Because I'm using more than one recaptcha in the same page, I had to use the  method and set it to explicit.
Anyway, I lost an entire day of searching to understand that I need to use grecaptcha.execute() to make it work, but it didn't work even with it, I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what exactly is it, here's some code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  var onloadCallback = function() {
    var recaptchas = document.querySelectorAll('div[class=g-recaptcha]');

   for( i = 0; i < recaptchas.length; i++) {
     grecaptcha.render( recaptchas[i].id, {
       'sitekey' : '',
       'badge' : 'inline',
       'size' : 'invisible'
      });
     grecaptcha.execute(i);
   }
 }
</script>
```

In the forms I'm using it like this:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="rc1"></div>
```

And in the end of the page:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

I really don't know why it isn't working now, I've set grecaptcha.execute to "i" because I've read that it's a 0 based index, so it should work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering how to do it, I got it to work by loading both explicitly, and it worked, like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>    
<script>
      var recaptcha1;
      var recaptcha2;
      var myCallBack = function() {
        //Render recaptcha1 on element with ID "recaptcha1"
        recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
          'sitekey' : 'your-site-key',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });

        //Render recaptcha2 on element with ID "recaptcha2"
        recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
          'sitekey' : 'your-site-key',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
      };
</script>
```